# How to create this type of xml using xelement in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

This is what I require:

```
<EuropeanSale>
 <VATCore:SubmittersReference>001</VATCore:SubmittersReference>
 <VATCore:CountryCode>AT</VATCore:CountryCode>
 <VATCore:CustomerVATRegistrationNumber>U52375709</VATCore:CustomerVATRegistrationNumber>
 <VATCore:TotalValueOfSupplies>1000</VATCore:TotalValueOfSupplies>
 <VATCore:TransactionIndicator>2</VATCore:TransactionIndicator>
</EuropeanSale>
```

This is my code:

```cs
XElement temp= new XElement("EuropeanSale", 
    new XElement("Vat:SubmittersReference", item.SubmittersReference), 
    new XElement("Vat:CountryCode", item.CountryCode), 
    new XElement("CustomerVATRegistrationNumber", item.CustomerVATRegistrationNumber), 
    new XElement("Vat:TotalValueOfSupplies", item.TotalValueOfSupplies), 
    new XElement("Vat:TransactionIndicator", item.TransactionIndicator) );
```

This is the exception:

> "The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name."

Comment: And what did you try so far? Where are you stuck? There are thousands of questions and topics about xml-serialization, either with Linq2Xml, or wirh `XmlSerializer` or even with `XmlReader`.

Comment: I am creating this type of xml in c# using xelement  but i am getting error

Comment: Please show exactly what you´ve tried and the error you get. We don´t like to guess what you problem *might* be.

Comment: XElement temp=  new XElement("EuropeanSale",
                                  new XElement("Vat:SubmittersReference", item.SubmittersReference),
                                   new XElement("Vat:CountryCode", item.CountryCode),
                                     new XElement("CustomerVATRegistrationNumber", item.CustomerVATRegistrationNumber),
                                       new XElement("Vat:TotalValueOfSupplies", item.TotalValueOfSupplies),
                                         new XElement("Vat:TransactionIndicator", item.TransactionIndicator) );

Comment: and the exception was "The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name."

Comment: Please post the code into the question, as it´s hard to read within the comments. Anyway the error is pretty clear, isn´t it? Omit the `Vat:` ffrom your `XmlElement`s.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to declare your namespace at the least in your parent element.
See if this can get you started:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create an XML tree in a namespace, with a specified prefix  
        XNamespace ns = "http://example.com";
        XElement root = new XElement("Root", 
                                     new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "VATCore", "http://example.com"), 
                                     new XElement(ns + "Child", "child content")
                                    );
        Console.WriteLine(root);
    }
}
```

The above outputs

```
<Root xmlns:VATCore="http://example.com">
  <VATCore:Child>child content</VATCore:Child>
</Root>
```

on https://dotnetfiddle.net/zedBb3.